# How to install both 32 and 64 bit versions of Java on the same computer

Tags: java

I need both Java 32 and 64 bit versions on my workstation, but when I try to install the 32 bit version it says I already have another Java version installed. This is for Java version 7 update 9. I can't delete the existing version via the configuration page, I tried a couple other things but I'm not very good with computers and so far nothing has worked. Can somebody please help? I have windows 7

Comment: Linux or Windows or Mac... what OS?

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271609/multiple-java-versions-running-concurrently-under-windows

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine for me. But I don't use java.com, I just download the runtime installers from oracle.com.