# Windows 7 64-bit, Configuring 2 versions of Java

Tags: java, windows

Windows 7 64bit. I have a web based application that needs to use the newest version of java (1.7.0.45) and I have another software install the needs java versions (1.5.0.15 & 1.4.2). I'm just unsure how to set the PATH/VARIABLE for this to work properly.. any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have seen several posts & answers regarding very similar situations to this, but I am just unsure how to make this work.

Comment: This question is more suitable for the Super User site

Comment: by "web based applications" what exactly do you mean? are they launched locally or via browser?

Comment: web browser - Internet Explorer

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Moshe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271609/multiple-java-versions-running-concurrently-under-windows).

> It is absolutely possible to install side-by-side several JRE/JDK
>   versions. Moreover, you don't have to do anything special for that to
>   happen, as Sun is creating a different folder for each (under Program
>   Files).
>
> There is no control panel to check which JRE works for each
>   application. Basically, the JRE that will work would be the first in
>   your PATH environment variable. You can change that, or the JAVA_HOME
>   variable, or create specific cmd/bat files to launch the applications
>   you desire, each with a different JRE in path. Just like below,
>
> ```
> set JAVA_HOME=C:\...\j2dskXXX to change the JAVA_HOME environment.
> ```

Comment: For some reason this is just not coming to me, I'm obviously stupid. haha   I can go into "System Properties" -> "Environment Variables" and set the JAVE_HOME variable.. Do I need to create 2 different JAVE_HOME variables?

Comment: I'm understanding a bit more now after finding more discussions about this.. I know how to set the JAVE_HOME variables, but what path do I point that to.. my new or old installed java versions?

Comment: You can create a batch (.bat) file that sets jre and then starts your application. Thus application will run on jre mentioned in batch file. Create multiple batch files for multiple jre's.

Comment: So create 2 batch files.. one to open Internet Explorer and one for the other s/w I'm using.

Comment: Suppose for app1 iw ant to run on jre6 then my batch file would be something like this,  1) set java_home // path to jre6                  2) start server/ app1                                                              And if i want to run app1 on jre7 then my new batch file would be like ,  1) set java_home // path to jre6                                    2) start server/ app1

Comment: What would be the command to "start" internet explorer?  start C:\Progra~1\Intern~1\iexplorer.exe

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"  www.google.com

Comment: Actually it's this:  start C:\Progra~2\Intern~1\iexplore.exe   btw I'm pretty aware of google, no reason to be a smartass.