# Changing the java version under use

Tags: java, version

I have both Java 6 and Java 7 on my computer (Windows7) but running command:

```
java -version
```

I got the following:

```
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

How can I set the java 7 as the default?

---

*Edit:* I've already updated the `PATH`, and in fact when I do

```
javac -version
```

...it gives me `1.7.0_11`, but `java -version` still gives me the above.

Comment: Change your `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables to point to Java 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to **Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings**
2. Click the **Environment Variables...** button
3. In the **System variables** box at the bottom, update the `Path` variable so that it includes the Java7 `bin` directory rather than the Java6 one
4. If you see a `JAVA_HOME` variable listed there, update it as well (if you don't see one, that's fine)

Once you've done that, you'll have to close and reopen any command prompts you have open.

---

Re your note below (which I've edited into the question):

> Actually I already have updated it. So, the java 6 path does not exist in my environmental variables. It is strange, if I check the: javac -version it returns: javac 1.7.0_11 but not for java -version.

Look at the `Path` again, I suspect you'll find that there are separate entries for the JDK's bin and the JRE's bin. That's normal. You probably updated the JDK's entry but not the JRE's.

Another thing to do is to find out where that `java.exe` file is located. You can do that like this:

```
where java.exe
```

That will search your path and show you where it finds the `java.exe` file. I was *very* surprised to find on a fresh Java8 install just now that it was in the `C:\Windows\System32` directory, so that may be what's going on on your system.

You may find [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271609/multiple-java-versions-running-concurrently-under-windows) useful, particularly the `STATIC=1` JRE installation option. That information appears to still relate to Java 7 at least.

Comment: Actually I already have updated it. So, the java 6 path does not exist in my environmental variables. It is strange, if I check the: javac -version it returns: javac 1.7.0_11 but not for java -version

Comment: @user30314: I've added further info to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

look into `C:\Windows\System32` you will find java.exe.
The `C:\Windows\System32` is before what you set.So put your java path before `C:\Windows\System32` like:
`%JAVA_HOME%\bin;...;%SystemRoot%\system32;`