# Use deployJava.js to check for latest JRE version for web applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet, deployjava

I like to use the deployJava.js to check which JRE version installed in system. When I read documentation of deployjava.js it seems that it will work perfectly. But it's not working exactly.
I tested it in Mac in which

```
 Browser | Version
 -------- --------
 Safari  |   1.5
 Firefox |   1.6
 Chrome  |   1.6
```

How it's possible that in single system browser has different JRE version?

Here is my code.

```
var installed_jre_version = deployJava.getJREs();
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>JRE Version :</td>
    <td>
      <script>
       if(installed_jre_version=='' || installed_jre_version==undefined){
           document.write("Not detected."); 
        }
       else
       {
          document.write(installed_jre_version); 
       }
      </script>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: it is possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271609/multiple-java-versions-running-concurrently-under-windows

Comment: Thanks #UmarHayat. Yeah, it is possible but in my case scenario is different. I have to run applet if JRE version is 1.6+ . While safari showing me version 1.5+, than how can I run applet in Safari.