# Installation of JFrog Artifactory in windows 10 gives an error message

Tags: windows, windows-10, artifactory

I am facing an issue, while installing JFrog Artifactory in windows 10. I have downloaded this version (jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.9.0) and created the needed environment variables in system settings.

**Here is the Java Version:**

```
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

**Here is the Maven Version:**

```
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T13:28:13+05:30)
Maven home: C:\dev\tools\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\..
Java version: 9.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

**Here is the trace:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.artifactory.api.repo.RepositoryService org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.repositoryService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.artifactory.api.request.UploadService org.artifactory.repo.service.RepositoryServiceImpl.uploadService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uploadServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.artifactory.storage.binstore.service.BinaryService org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.binaryService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.artifactory.api.request.UploadService org.artifactory.repo.service.RepositoryServiceImpl.uploadService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uploadServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.artifactory.storage.binstore.service.BinaryService org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.binaryService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 73 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.artifactory.api.request.UploadService org.artifactory.repo.service.RepositoryServiceImpl.uploadService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uploadServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.artifactory.storage.binstore.service.BinaryService org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.binaryService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 84 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uploadServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.artifactory.storage.binstore.service.BinaryService org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.binaryService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 86 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.artifactory.storage.binstore.service.BinaryService org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.binaryService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 97 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1558)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 99 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.config.ConfigurableBinaryProviderManager.buildByConfig(ConfigurableBinaryProviderManager.java:57)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.manager.BinaryProviderManagerImpl.<init>(BinaryProviderManagerImpl.java:102)
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.binstore.service.BinaryServiceImpl.initialize(BinaryServiceImpl.java:176)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
        ... 111 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
        ... 121 common frames omitted
```

**Steps followed for installation:**

1. Extracted the artifactory zip to this location (C:\dev\tools)
2. Inside bin directory (C:\dev\tools\artifactory-oss-5.9.0\bin), have run "artifactory.bat" as Administrator and hit into the above trace.

**Note** It was a quite long trace, and I have just copied last few ones. If you guys need the full stack trace, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory [requires](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/System+Requirements) Java 8 while you are using Java 9. The root cause of this error is related to changes introduced in Java 9 which are not backward compatible (see more info [here](http://ClassNotFoundException:%20javax.xml.bind.JAXBException)).
There is an open [request](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-15061) for supporting Java 9 you can follow. Until this is resolved you will need to use Java 8.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Just wanted to check, is there a way to manage multiple version of java on windows machine? Or do I need to remove the current one (Java9) and install version Java8?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple version of Java in parallel. See the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271609/multiple-java-versions-running-concurrently-under-windows