# How to install Java 8 along with Java 9 in Windows 7

Tags: java

How can I install Java 8 along with Java 9... I want both.

Please tell how to set both of their path so that I can use both of them.

Comment: Download each version’s installer and run it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271609/multiple-java-versions-running-concurrently-under-windows

Comment: Once you have both, why do you want both on the path? How will you determine which you are using, are you going to rename the executables from one of them?

Comment: please do some simple research work . this is a more general question.